# c++ mysql++ librarys

Tags: c++, mysql++

I want a mysql connection with C++ to my database. I downloaded the files from http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/

I wasn't able to successfully install it and get the libraries in the c:/mysql++ folder.
Can somebody help / do it for me and upload it :).

Comment: So show the error messages. By the way remove "can somebody help / do it for me and upload it". I think this is not the way problems get solved here.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest start to me in ***"mysql & C++"*** case was *libmysql*. Easy to build, easy to use. After writing your own trivial C++ - way wrappers for C routines it becomes very convenient and powerful.

*Guess that is not the answer to your question, BUT actually I don't see the question)*

U R WELKOM! greetz Kotti